# How to format HTML in Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, formatting, sublimetext3

I’m using Sublime 3 to prepare HTML files that will eventually be turned into an epub in Sigil. This is working very well except that the formatting isn’t helping the readability.
I have HTMLbeautify and HTML/CSS/JSPrettify. They do a great job with the indentation but I would also like a method of putting the opening and closing paragraph tags on new lines, something like

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse rutrum dolor in lacus efficitur consequat. Cras turpis dolor, pretium sit  amet tincidunt sed, porta iaculis lectus. Morbi consectetur vitae justo eu  pretium.
</p>
```

Can anybody help?

I've read all the other Sublime/HTML formatting queries and i can't find anything that quite covers this.

Answer (score 3):

Just select all lines (`Ctrl` `A`) and then from the menu select Edit → Line → Reindent. This will work